# Cannot find 'UIAlertController' in scope error in swift?

Tags: swift, alert

Why I am getting  `Cannot find 'UIAlertController' in scope?` error if i write alert function in separate swift file or if i use extension its not coming to another viewcontroller why?

code:

```
 func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:
    message, preferredStyle: .alert)
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in
  }))
  self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

error:

> Cannot find 'UIAlertController' in scope,

> Cannot find 'UIAlertAction' in scope

> Cannot find 'self' in scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you forgot this in your viewController:

```
import UIKit
```

so your file has no idea what `UIAlertController` or `UIAlertAction` is

if you want to create an alert view controller to be used across multiple UIViewController you can do this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomAlertController: NSObject {
    
    let message:String?
    let title:String?
    
    init(title:String, message:String) {
        self.message = message
        self.title = title
    }
    

    func showAlert()->UIAlertController {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: self.title, message: self.message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        // you can further customize your buttons, buttons' title etc 
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in
        }))
        return alertController
    }
    
}
```

then your view controllers

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let alert = CustomAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "My message to the world")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert.showAlert(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now `Cannot find 'self' in scope` is i delete self then `Cannot find 'present' in scope`

Comment: so you want to use that function across multiple view controllers?

Comment: yes, want to use that function across multiple view controllers